# Java Method add ArrayList is undefined for the type <OBJECT>

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist, undefined

I am building a java program for my homework where I must add product to particular store. I have trouble when trying to add to ArrayList from Store class.

I have class product as follows:

```
class Product {

    private String pName;
    private int pPrice;
    private int pQty;

    public Product (String pName, int pPrice, int pQty) {
        this.pName = pName;
        this.pPrice = pPrice;
        this.pQty = pQty;
    }
}
```

And class store as follows:

```
class Store {

    private String storeName;
    ArrayList<Product> pList =new ArrayList<>();

    public Store() {
        String name = storeName;
        pList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }
    public Store(String newStoreName,ArrayList<Product> newPList) {
        this.storeName = newStoreName;
        this.pList = newPList;
    }

    void setName(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }
    void setProduct(Product pList) {
        pList.add(this.pList);//This return method add undefined for type Product, how to solve this error?
    }
    String getName() {
        return storeName;
    }
    ArrayList<Product> getProductList() {
        return pList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You put your `this.` on the wrong `pList`, so it's trying to call an `add()` method on a `Product` with a `List<Product>` as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void setProduct(Product pList) {
    pList.add(this.pList);//This return method add undefined for type Product, how to solve this error?
}
```

should be

```
void addProduct(Product product) {
    pList.add(product);
}
```

Comment: `this.pList.add(pList)` would have also worked, but this solution is much better: simultaneously eliminating the confusion between `pList` and `this.pList` while also giving the method param a much more meaningful and relevant name.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You should change you constructor like below :_-

```
public Store(String newStoreName,ArrayList<Product> newPList) {
    this.storeName = newStoreName;
    pList.addAll(newPList);// This is standard and recommended way to add all element in list. 
}
```

2 - change your setProduct method. this operator does not work like this.

```
void setProduct(Product pList) {
    pList.add(pList); 
}
```